# What is a "minor-minor" seventh chord?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, terminology

In the question "[difficulty with chord spelling and voicing in Neumeyer's Hindemith analysis](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/113904/70803)", reference is made to a "minor-minor" seventh chord.

> Note that the 'VI-with-upward-sloping-line-through-'I'', despite its duration, becomes the weakest link in the harmony because its correct root lies high and contradicts the stereotype of the minor-minor seventh chord.

I thought I was familiar with all the different seventh chords, like dominant and half-diminished, and I know minor sevenths, of course, but what is "minor-minor"?

Comment: In all the years of playing, (65+), I've never ever come across a 'minor-minor seventh chord, by such a name! Plenty of m7, etc. though.

Comment: @Tim A first for me as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Minor-minor seventh** is another name for **minor seventh**.

There is a naming convention for (some) seventh chords that specifies the underlying triad plus the seventh above the root.

- minor-minor = minor (e.g., `C - Eb - G - Bb`)
- minor-major = minor-major (e.g., `C - Eb - G - B`)
- major-minor = dominant (e.g., `C - E - G - Bb`)

These designations can be seen on Wikipedia, for example:

- [Minor/minor seventh chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_seventh_chord): "A seventh chord with a minor third, perfect fifth, and minor seventh is commonly called a minor seventh chord, but also sometimes a minor/minor seventh chord.
- [Minor/major seventh chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_seventh_chord): "When the seventh note [over a minor triad] is a major seventh above the root, it is called a minor/major seventh chord."
- [Dominant seventh chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominant_seventh_chord): "In music theory, a dominant seventh chord, or major minor seventh chord ... is a major triad together with a minor seventh."

Comment: So basically C-minor-minor-7th is to be read as C-minor + minor 7th instead of C-minor-minor + 7th.

Comment: @Lazy Yes, exactly: triad-type + (major-/minor-)-seventh.

Comment: Don't understand the two comments. Cmm7 is just C minor, with minor 7th added. Major minor 7th is dominant 7th, surely? (and occasionally called that).

Comment: @Tim Yes, that's what both comments are saying. You've understood correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a minor seventh chord. Rather like dominant 7th chords are rarely called that, due to their preponderance in music 'play C7 there'; minor minor 7ths are simply called m7. 'Play Cm7 there'. It.'s clear that it's a minor triad with the addition of a m7. Hence Cmm7 - abbreviated to Cm7.

There is quite a rare chord called minor major seventh, which is usually a transitionary between minor and m7, but that occurs so infrequently, we keep the name - mM7.

Answer (score 1):

Minor-minor 7th.  Minor triad with a minor 7th.   Cm7.

As compared with Major-minor 7th. Major triad with a minor 7th. 'Dom7'.  C7.

Or Minor-major 7th. Minor triad with a major 7th. Cm(maj7).

All are exactly what their names say!